# in bash script; a process stdout as filename argument fails when you open it more than one time

Tags: bash, stdout, file-descriptors

Consider this bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bug_part() {
    cat $1 > sample.first
    cat $1 > sample.second #second time you open file $1, it contains no data
}

bug_part <(echo "TEST")
[ "$(cat sample.first)" != "$(cat sample.second)" ] && echo "THIS IS A BUG" 1>&2 && exit 1
rm sample.first sample.second
```

Do you agree with me that this problem is bash bug?  Or Linux bug?

Is there anybody that knows exactly what's happening behind?

Comment: Side note: comparing files is `diff`'s job. Using `cat` in such a way is the best way to mess stuff up with empty files, newlines and other metacharacters, should you make a mistake in quoting. `if diff f1 f2; then ...`

Comment: @JohnWHSmith this was just a fast test, for two 4-character files. in real cases, I prefer to use a hash function (like `md5sum`) to check context-equality of general files

Comment: If you open `/dev/urandom` twice, you won't get the same data twice.  (You also won't get EOF, but that's another problem.)  If you read from the terminal twice, you won't get the same data twice unless the user is boringly repetitive.  If you open a FIFO twice, you won't get the same data twice.  If you open a socket twice, you won't get the same data twice.  `/dev/mem`, `/dev/kmem`, non-rewind tape devices… There are lots of devices where you can't read the same data twice even if you open it twice and try reading from it again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler totally agree with you, BUT, when stdout(or other ostream) of a process is redirected to another process by `<(` (it would pass the name of stream `/dev/fd/...` to the other process) , I think that re-opening of this filename is just have the meaning that **provide the same data**

Comment: @MostafaNazari: no, and I already gave examples where it doesn't apply (almost anything except a disk file).  The device that is used with process redirection is not a disk file.  You are not guaranteed to be able to read the same data twice even if you open it twice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are saying facts, BUT, Think for a moment, have you ever call s.th. like `vim /dev/urandom`? only files could be reopened from beginning, YES, but filename as argument are widely used in linux applications. in the case I was involved, I had an external process that opens the filename in argument twice.I would never call that process with /dev/urandom or any other thing, because it is meaningless. but piping stdout of another process to it, I need it. now with your opinion, I should store in tempfile and the call process, which cost me twice execution time, and disk cost...

Comment: @MostafaNazari: Either `tee` or a tmpfile is not going to be much difference in execution time, unless the file is many megabytes.  If it's small, it'll just stay in RAM and then get deleted.  If it's big, having both processes that need to read it from start to finish running at once, from different outputs of `tee`, will save time.  (Have `tee` write to a pipe pipe, either with `>(cmd2)` process substitution or a named pipe.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's a bug.  You can read from / write to a named pipe connected to commands prepared by [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) only once.

Comment: Pipes work on a consumer/producer basis. Once data has been read by a process, it is removed from the pipe's queue. The consumer will be able to read again, if the producer writes to the pipe again :)

Comment: If you test the bash implementation of operator `<(` you would use that it would execute the process inside parenthesis and send the name of stdout file descriptor `/dev/fd/...` as an argument value to outside process. now, in general purpose, if the inside application decide to open-and-read the file twice, this would cause problem in second reading. but if you call outside process with a real persisted file, this would not happened

Comment: @MostafaNazari: yes, exactly.  If you want a real file, use a here-string, like `cmd <<<"$text"`.  You might need some extra redirections or `cat /dev/stdin` to open the file twice, instead of having the 2nd `cat` try to read from the same fd that's still at EOF from the first `cat`'s use.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in your script.  Use `tee` if you want to duplicate data that can only be read once.  As the other answer explains, <(cmd) makes a pipe, and puts `/dev/fd/62` or similar on the command line:

```
echo <(true)
  /dev/fd/63
```

Another alternative to `tee` is a here-string:

```
cmd <<<"$text"
```

If you want bash to make a seekable tmp file and redirect input from that.  (I'm not sure exactly how you'd rewind stdin to the beginning of the file inside your function, though.  I think `cat /dev/stdin` might just get the same file position.)

Comment: `<<<` doesn't give you a regular file either, it uses a pipe. If you want a regular, seekable file, you have to create one. Or avoid trying to read the file twice.

Comment: @GordonDavisson:  The bash docs don't guarantee it, but the current implementation (bash4.3) writes the string to a file like `/tmp/sh-thd-1045505329`, opens it, redirects stdin from it, then unlinks it.  `strace -f -efile,write,read,dup2 bash -c 'cat <<< foo'` to see it in action.

Comment: Wow, you're right; I though I'd tested that before commenting, but apparently not...

Comment: @PeterCordes It is obvious that I write this simple code to make the problem clear. but consider **you don't know what's going on** in function `bug_part`, and if it opens the file twice, all thing go wrong without any error or alert! using `<<<` is not a solution for me (I test it and the same error still exists). my problem is why `bash` did not consider multiple opening of redirected streams by `<(` or even another operator

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Peter Cordes' suggestion of using `tee` instead of trying to read the file (/pipe) twice, here's a possible rewrite of the function:

```
bugless_part() {
    tee sample.first >sample.second <"$1"
}
```

When run as `bugless_part <(echo "TEST")`, it puts "TEST" in both files.

Comment: I really like your Idea, You totally understand the problem, and the proper solution as I did. but The question is, would you agree with me about that this is a `bash` bug? because the usage of a sub-process in this way, depends on the implementation, and I think `bash` should handle this requirement, not me. **At least** it provides another operator to handle this

Comment: @MostafaNazari It's not a bug (and actually doesn't have anything to do with bash), it's just the way pipes work. When you read from a pipe (e.g. with the first `cat`), the data you read is removed the from the pipe -- there's just no way to go back and read it again, because the data isn't there anymore. That's why the second `cat` didn't get anything.